# Some WIX extension tags write rows to CreateFolder table which lead to Not-Uninstallable Patch

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch, uninstallation, create-directory

I found an issue in WIX extension implementation.

Some WIX extension tags write rows to **CreateFolder** table, e.g. , , . As the official MSI document says, a patch can be **Not uninstallable** if it contains new rows in the **CreateFolder** table. I think such extensions can be implemented without the usage of the **CreateFolder** table. It's really bad to block patch uninstall just because the usage of these extensions. There is a [screenshot](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20140822111014796?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvcGt1ZHp5/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/Center) which shows my **CreateFolder** table in Orca.exe.

Is this a known issue in WIX? Will future versions fix this issue?

Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372102(v=vs.85).aspx for more information about Not Uninstallable Patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyPath : This value points to a file or folder belonging to the component that the installer uses to detect the component. It is creating entry in CreateFolder of MSI because of KeyPath is provide at component level that is taking installation folder as its key so your patch become not uninstallable.

Provide KeyPath at one of the file of component that is the most important for that component. So it does not make entry into CreatFolder table of MSI and your patch become uninstallable.